# Nested Coroutine : type of parent coroutine dispatcher

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-android-extensions, coroutinescope

I am trying to implement Async Task functionality with Coroutines. With the below snippet, I am able to achieve Async Task functionality.

```
fun execute(vararg params: Params?) {
    job = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            onPreExecute()
        }

        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            doInBackground(*params)
        }

        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            onPostExecute(result)
        }
    }
}
```

I am only worried about, which dispatcher to use on parent coroutine. Is it  Dispatchers.Default (or) Dispatchers.IO.
With the both dispatchers functionality is working fine.

Is it correct to use Dispatchers.IO ?,

1. Its because of more no of available threads in thread pool.
2. There may be delay involved with Dispatchers.Default, As it has limited threads.

Is it correct to use Dispatchers.Default ?,

1. As It is backed by a shared pool of threads on JVM.
2. As it is parent of 3 child coroutines ?
3. As it is parent of coroutine having Dispatchers.Main

Note : Correct me, if my above understanding is wrong.

Problem area : What is the suitable dispatcher to use for parent dispatcher ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `Dispatchers.Main` as a context for coroutine scope:

```
fun execute(vararg params: Params?) {
    job = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
        onPreExecute()

        val result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            doInBackground(*params)
        }

        onPostExecute(result)
    }
}
```

In that case you don't need to switch contexts to `Dispatchers.Main` for `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` functions.